# Unable to resolve assembly Model.dll

Tags: .net, entity-framework, reflection

I had a class library project that used Entity Framework and it worked fine until I moved the model out to a separate class library type project.

After I moved the model out to a separate class library project called Model, I changed the connection string in the app/web.config to read as follows:

```
<add name="GlobalizationEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://Model.dll/Models.ResourceGlobalizationModel.csdl|
res://Model.dll/Models.ResourceGlobalizationModel.ssdl|
res://Model.dll/Models.ResourceGlobalizationModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
Data Source=MyComputer\sqlexpress;
Initial Catalog=DaDatabase;
Integrated Security=true;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

(I've included line breaks in the snippet above on purpose only for readability. My code does not have those line breaks.)

Now, my solution structure looks like this:

[image]

However, I get a `FileNotFound` exception at run-time that reads:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Unable to resolve assembly 'Model.dll'.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.ResolveAssemblyName(String assemblyName, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)
       at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
       at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
       at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
       at Resources.BaseServices.Globalization.Models.ResourceGlobalizationEntities..ctor() in C:\SVN\Model\ResourceGlobalizationEntities.cs:line 7
       at Resources.BaseServices.Globalization.Models.Culture.IsValidCulture(String shortName) in C:\SVN\Model\Culture.cs:line 24
       at Resources.BaseServices.Globalization.EntityFrameworkStringResourceLoader.set_CultureName(String value) in C:\SVN\BusinessObjects\EntityFrameworkStringResourceLoader.cs:line 129
       at Resources.BaseServices.Globalization.EntityFrameworkStringResourceLoader..ctor(String cultureName, IDataSource dataSource) in C:\SVN\BusinessObjects\EntityFrameworkStringResourceLoader.cs:line 19
  InnerException:
```

I tried the scenario with 2 clients, namely, a console app and an MVC app.

While the console app does not even copy `BusinessObjects.dll` and its referenced dlls, namely, the `Model.dll` to the console application's `bin` directory, the MVC app does. Yet, both of them seem not to find the `Model.dll` assembly at all, and raise the above-mentioned `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Did you check the platform (AnyCPU, x86) and target framework for every project?

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  Its trace shows you where it looked for the file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. Fuslogvw.exe doesn't report anything at all. As in, it didn't generate logs at all, which leads me to believe that it only works with compiled/deployed binaries. I'd test my project in a deployed environment but that's too much of a time investment. I've solved my problem already. I'll post the solution soon. Time crunch. Thanks much, though.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: I am having same problem too

Comment: It worked for me when I added Model reference to consoleClient. But I don't want to do it

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 What was your solution?

Answer (score 8):

1) Change `res://Model.dll/` to `res://Model/` (without the '.dll' extension) in all places in your connection string. You can also specify the full name of the assembly, for example: `res://Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null/` (more info at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx).

2) Next, make sure that the following namespace is valid: `Model.Models.ResourceGlobalizationModel`. If not, change the connection string and/or the assembly name accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from the EF ConStr. Usually, when you want to use an embedded resource, you should set the `Metadata` like the following:

```
Metadata=res://<assemblyFullName>/<resourceName>.
```

You also can use the `*` wildcard instead of `<assemblyFullName>`. It causes the to search the following locations for the file at runtime:

- The calling assembly.
- The referenced assemblies.
- The assemblies in the bin directory of an application.

More info is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc716756.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. If you look at the question closely, that's exactly what I have already done.

Comment: But you doesn't set the assembly...! the correct format is `metadata=res://<assemblyFullName>/Model.dll`. Am I wrong?!

Comment: Entity Framework delegates the assembly look up to the default assembly resolver available in the .NET framework, which is a part of the reflection API. You can give it the full assembly name or just the name.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved `Ecom.edfx` EF model to it's own folder (`Ecom`).
Check in `Web.config`/(`app.config`) if EF connection string generated has it's metadata set as following

```
<add name="EcomEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Ecom.Ecom.csdl|res://*/Ecom.Ecom.ssdl|res://*/Ecom.Ecom.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

(Directory structure is done with `.`(dot) not `/`(slash)) like following **res://*/Ecom.Ecom.csdl*** (from being **res:///Ecom.csdl** while not in it's own folder).